# Compiled Matlab function works only once

Tags: c#, c, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have a Matlab function compiled into C library. I am using this library from C# application.

If I call my function in C library for the first time, everything works fine, but the second call causes an exception - mlfMyfunc returns null pointer insted pointer to results (output1 and output2 parameters are IntPtr.Zero even after mlfMyfunc call)

My `DoubleArray` class (wrapper around `mx...` functions), is well tested and I think it works correctly.

Do you have any idea where problem could be?

Thanks. Lukas

C# code:

```
using Native;

 class MatlabAlgosBridge {
   [DllImport("Algos.dll"]
   private static extern bool AlgosInitialize();

   [DllImport("Algos.dll")]
   private static extern void AlgosTerminate();

   [DllImport("Algos.dll")]
   private static extern bool mlfMyfunc([In] int nargout, ref IntPtr output1, ref IntPtr output2, [In] IntPtr xVar, [In] IntPtr time, [In] IntPtr algoParam, [In] IntPtr Ts, [In] IntPtr codes);

  public List<double> Analyze(List<double> xValues) {
    double[] result = null;
    try {
      Native.Mcl.mclInitializeApplication("NULL", 0)
      AlgosInitialize();

      DoubleArray xValM = DoubleArray.CreateMatrix(xValues.Data.Count, 1);
      // Other parameter initialization 

      IntPtr output1 = IntPtr.Zero;
      IntPtr output2 = IntPtr.Zero;

      mlfMyfunc(2, ref output1, ref output2, xValM.Pointer, time.Pointer, params.Pointer, ts.Pointer, codes.Pointer);

      result = new MArray(output1).AsDoubleVector();
    }
    finally {
      AlgosTerminate();
      Native.Mcl.mclTerminateApplication();
    }

    return result;
   }
}
```

**Solution:**

The problem was caused by repetitionary Matlab engine initialization. Each time I call Analyze function the engine gets initialized (`Native.Mcl.mclInitializeApplication`] and even it's being properly terminated (`Native.Mcl.mclTerminateApplication`) in `finally` block, something goes wrong with repetitionary initialization. Built in matlab functions still works properly, but my library don't.

The solution is moving `mclInitializeApplication` call outside Analyze function and ensuring it's called only once in application lifetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by repetitionary Matlab engine initialization. Each time I call `Analyze` function the engine gets initialized (`Native.Mcl.mclInitializeApplication`) and even it's being properly terminated (`Native.Mcl.mclTerminateApplication`) in finally block, something goes wrong with repetitionary initialization. Built in matlab functions still works properly, but my library don't.

The solution is moving `mclInitializeApplication` call outside `Analyze` function and ensuring it's called only once in application lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

try to allocate IntPtrs using globalAlloc

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it didn't work. Problem was with Matlab engine initialization - see my edited question